# wpf what happens if ShowDialog() is called from a non-UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

So I currently have this code below, which has a background worker call showdialog().  However, I thought that the UI cannot be updated on a background thread, so how does the dialog display? Does the dialog actually get opened on the UI thread? what happens?

```
 public partial class ProgressDialog : Window
 { 
    BackgroundWorker _worker;
    public BackgroundWorker Worker
    {
      get { return _worker; }
    }

    public void RunWorkerThread(object argument, Func<object> workHandler)
    {
      //store reference to callback handler and launch worker thread
      workerCallback = workHandler;
      _worker.RunWorkerAsync(argument);

      //display modal dialog (blocks caller)
      //never returns null, but is a nullable boolean to match the dialogresult property
      ShowDialog();
    }
```

I have gotten suggestions that I just run the code and check, but how do i check whether the show dialog window was opened on a new thread or on the background thread itself? Not sure how I would check that.

Anyway this was just a post to try to help my understanding of what is actually happening in my code.

Anyway finally understood more of the comments, so I think I understand everything that is going on. Most of my real problems weren't caused by this dialog anyway, they were caused by updating observable collections from a non-ui thread while controls were bound to them.

Comment: What don't you try? It would take less time than asking here..

Comment: If it is a STA thread and it owns your Dialog, then nothing.

Comment: no, i have tried it. it runs, i don't understand why it runs. Maybe i'm wrong, but I thought that only the UI thread can perform UI operations

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet There's no reason why only one thread can be a UI thread. The only problem is when two different threads are accessing the *same* objects (including user interface elements) in ways that the objects cannot handle. And accessing controls will typically indirectly access other controls too, which is why it's often easier to have only one UI thread, but there's no hard requirement for that.

Comment: Are you sure `ShowDialog()` is being called from the method executed by the `BackgroundWorker`? You are starting the execution of the Worker in that same method. It seems that you're starting the background task and then showing the dialog...

Comment: This code snippet *starts* a worker thread, there's very little evidence that it actually creates the dialog on the worker thread as well.  A BackgroundWorker's thread is not suitable for UI, such a thread is not a single-threaded apartment and therefore does not permit common Windows facilities like drag+drop, the clipboard, cut and paste and shell dialogs.  Plenty of WPF classes complain as well.

Comment: thanks oscar. wasn't thinking straight, your comment made me realize what was going on. I was looking for a problem here because i wanted the problem to be here, but actually it was elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are not changing a property on your Main thread just creating a instance of another object.

But it could help if you elaborate a bit more on your method ShowDialog().

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem with calling *ShowDialog()* from non-UI thread. And my answer is that **it depends on the thread which calls the ShowDialog()**. If you set the *ApartamentState* property for this thread before its start then everything will work as called from the UI thread. I have finally ended up with such a code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    // MessageBox.Show(foo.DirPath) - this works as a charm but 
    // if, it is called from non UI thread needs special handling as below.
    await Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show(foo.DirPath));
}

public class Foo
{
    private string dirPath;
    public string DirPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (dirPath == null)
            {
                var t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    using (var dirDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                    {
                        if (dirDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            dirPath = dirDialog.SelectedPath;
                    }
                }
                );
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();
                t.Join();
            }
            return dirPath;
        }
        set
        {
            dirPath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I dont know for sure but i thought that the showDialog doesnt create the object only showing it. So when u say ShowDialog it only tells to show. So it will run on the UI thread instead of the backgroundworker
(dont know for sure)

Comment: That's what usually throws an exception. Creating a control in another thread is not a problem. Accessing their properties is. The `Dispatcher` will check whether the calling thread is the owner thread, and it'll cause an error. Think that you could be calling `ShowDialog()` at the same time other thread is calling `Close()`.

Comment: SO is `Question&Answer` site not `Question&MyGuess`